# How does juju expose work?

Tags: juju, maas

If I expose my service, for instance teamspeak server, on what address it will be running? On my server address?

For example: my server has an address of 158.37.15.167. If I deploy teamspeak from my local network (10.0.0.0) connected to the server, how will it be seen in the 158.37.15.167 network?

When I run `juju status` I get this:

```
public-address: nodeTWO.localdomain
```

instead of an IP address. My juju status: http://pastebin.com/z99Bhx9G

Comment: Can you explain what type of environment this is? ec2? maas? local? openstack? It looks like maas, but I can't be sure. A full output of 'juju status' would help too

Comment: I am using local instances.

Answer (score 1):

It should use the public address to your server.

You can verify the actual address by running `juju status` and looking at the `public-address` stanza.

Comment: But I get this "public-address: nodeTWO.localdomain" instead of IP address.

Comment: Is DNS server(on ubuntu server) needed for proper working of juju and exposing services?

Answer (score 1):

Expose only manipulates provider-backed firewalls. Currently in juju there are 4 providers. EC2, OpenStack, MaaS and local. Only EC2 and OpenStack do anything on expose/unexpose because they have provider level firewalls through security groups.

This is changing in juju-core, the port to the go language. This bit of the architecture has proven difficult to scale beyond a certain number of machines. HP Cloud, for instance, limits us to 10 security groups per region, so with the current scheme one can only spin up 10 machines in HP Cloud. So juju-core handles this through something called the "firewaller" which will basically manage firewalls on the machines themselves rather than at the provider level.

https://launchpad.net/juju-core for more info on the port to go.

Comment: Is this still the case? Can you please tell me what "expose" does on the latest Juju?

Comment: @Galgalesh juju expose performs similar functionality - manipulating security groups and firewalls, but there are now providers and those providers are more robust than in 2012.